# cast from Iunknown to another type

Tags: c++, command-line-interface

i need to cast a variable from Iunknown type to another 
type(SpaceClaim::Api::V10::Session^)  i m working with c  /cli  and i can't find any solution

to fix that prb   here is the code :

```
 gcroot<SpaceClaim::Api::V10::Session^>  m_piApplication;  

STDMETHODIMP CEMWCADLinkCtrl::SetEMWCADLinkApplication(IUnknown* pCADApplication)
 {  
if ( pCADApplication == NULL ) 
return S_FALSE;  
 m_piApplication = (SpaceClaim::Api::V10::Session^)pCADApplication;  //error
  return S_OK;  }
```

plz if there is some one how can help ill be very gratful   thks,

Comment: **Never** cast a COM interface pointer. use [`QueryInterface()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682521(v=vs.85).aspx) with the appropriate IID and resulting output interface pointer type for the interface you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IUnknown is the base class for all COM objects whereas a C++/CLI ref class will have the .NET Object as its base class. There's no casting from one to other as they are not related in any way. If you're in C++ you should be calling pCADApplication->QueryInterface() to get at the interface you really need and then calling the methods on that. I highly recommend using the ATL smart pointers to help manage the reference counts (and many other generally useful COM helper functions).